# Unity 5 Terrain for mobile (Android)

Tags: unity-game-engine

Are there any terrain settings (unity 5.4b) that will make it usable (30+fps) for Android phones? I followed this link http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/the-secret-to-great-terrain-on-mobile.305899/ but was unsuccessful.

I tried setting a resolution of width 50,length 50, no trees or foliage, with a maximum pixel error  and with 2 low res textures (256) but it already lags on Android (Samsung S7 Edge).

Any alternative solution is also welcome since T4M is not supported in Unity 5. I want to be able to paint textures and raise/lower the ground as well.

Answer (score 2):

I recreated the issue, but after building and running the game on the phone directly, there was no lag what so-ever (Samsung Galaxy Note 4)

Make sure you are not using the Unity Remote 4 to test how the game runs on your android phone. Unity Remote 4 basically lets Unity stream the video onto the phone and lets the phone push inputs onto Unity.

Build and Run the game and play it directly from the phone instead, and you should notice no issues.

Comment: Hmm, what are your settings for your terrain? I ended up using a terrain exporter to generate the mesh and then Splat Painter to paint the generated mesh. It runs significantly smoother now on the phone

Comment: I just created a Unity terrain with width of 50, height of 50, player around with the terrain so its not just smooth, set pixel error to maximum, and created simple 256 shaders to simulate yours. Not sure what went wrong for you though. There might be something my setup is missing that yours has. Id use a Profiler in those cases though, might give you a better picture as to what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

just make sure you set the distance off it should
solve your problem tell me if the problem still there

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).